# Fade image in and out?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I make a image fade in and out constantly between 40% and 100%?

I tried with making a CSS3 opacity, but that only supports 0% and 100%, so it doesn't really fade.

Any ideas how to make this?

Comment: use jquery fadeTo to get the desired effect

Comment: "but [CSS3 opacity] only supports 0% and 100%" sounds unlikely.

Comment: @JanDvorak Well, i tried making a CSS3 Animation to fade in and out the image, but it went only on and off like the light. (0% to 100%, like it doesn't support opacity on 0,4)

Comment: @MarkoLivendo I don't expect `0,4` to work. Did you try `0.4` or `40%`?

Answer (score 2):

CSS Opacity supports the full range...

Just in decimal format.

EDIT: Added cross-browser opacity.

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)";
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
-moz-opacity: 0.4;
-khtml-opacity: 0.4;
opacity:0.4;
```

Comment: I tried that, but without luck. Thats why I came here to ask, as it was the method I was used to do.

Comment: @MarkoLivendo - You may have a browser that doesn't support the standard `opacity` declaration. I've updated above to add a cross-browser method for applying opacity.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you apply jQuery to this situation:

**Fade Out to 40%**

```
function fadOut() {
    $('img').animate({'opacity':'0.4'}, 500); // 500 is the time in milliseconds
}
```

**Fade In to 100%**

```
function fadIn() {
    $('img').animate({'opacity':'1.0'}, 500); // 500 is the time in milliseconds
}
```

To constantly run it, try

```
var timer = setTimeout(fadOut, 1000); // after every 1 sec it will fadOut

clearTimer(timer); // to clear the timer
```

Comment: Thanks a lto. But how will I make it constantly run? And aswell fadein again, as this is ment to fade only out to 40%.. right?

Comment: I have updated my code. I would like to know more, what you exactly want to do, to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

What Adrian said is correct however if you are like me and terrible with CSS, you can use [TwitterBootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap) The fade classes in there as well as all the other cool things you can do may help you a little more.

Comment: Isn't Bootstrap just like the jquery libary?